# Can you identify this mini figure with black Darth Vader-like helmet

Tags: minifigure-identification

I got it in a big box of pieces.
[image: mini figure with black Darth Vader-like helmet]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [NI-L8 Protocol Droid](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw1136) from set [75300-1 Imperial TIE Fighter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75300-1).

Note that it is similar to (and shares a head with) [Death Star Droid](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw0768) but that figure doesn't have the colorful wires in the waist area.